# Model contains null values when retrieved from database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework

Say I have three classes in my Model (omitting id etc.):

```
public class Foo() {
  public Bar Bar {get; set;}
  public List<Baz> Bazs {get; set;}
}

public class Bar() {
  public List<Foo> Foos {get; set;}
}

public Baz() {

}
```

When I create Foo and save it to model through a create view, it contains all the objects within it just fine. But when I retrieve it from database, it contains nulls. The table that stores Foo contains no columns for Bar and Baz. The tables for Bar and Baz, however, do contain a column Foo_Id. Which is fine, because Entity Framework handles these mappings automatically.

But why am I getting nulls when retrieving from database? I did the exact same thing for another model and it works fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a `virtual` before the fields did the trick.

Updated Model:

```
public class Foo() {
  public virtual Bar Bar {get; set;}
  public virtual List<Baz> Bazs {get; set;}
}

public class Bar() {
  public virtual List<Foo> Foos {get; set;}
}

public Baz() {

}
```